# Swift - WKInterfaceTable not scrolling to bottom

Tags: objective-c, swift, apple-watch, watchos-2, wkinterfacetable

i have 5 row controllers in **WKInterfaceTable**. I want to scroll to bottom of the table.

```
messagesTable.scrollToRowAtIndex(6)
```

From the apple documentation

> The index of the row to be displayed. Specifying an index less than 0 scrolls to the top of the list. Specifying an index greater than the total number of row controllers scrolls to the bottom of the list.

when i am giving Zero it is scrolling to top but when i give index greater than the total number of row controllers it do not scroll to bottom.

I tried giving last row controller index and it scrolled to it alright. but giving any value greater than last row controller index do not scroll it to bottom.
What i need to do to make it work?